# Clean URL links from table of contents in MS Word

Tags: url, ms-word, hyperlink

I don't know how appropriate it is to ask a question about MS Word here but I'll do so anyway..

I have a word document and I am exporting it to html, I have a table of contents, with links to the appropriate headings. The issue is that when I click on a link, it gives me something like a #Toc_81682617 in the url. Is it possible to instead have a #Summary or #1.1Summary

Thanks in advance to any enlightened souls out there

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking questions, please add some code that shows what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

This should be in a comment but I am not allowed to comment because too new.

This would be better posted in the [Word Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word) forum hosted by Microsoft. This forum is about programming.

That said, as far as I know, this is the nature of automatic bookmarks generated by Word. I know of no way of automatically modifying them.